# Mongodb Cxx Driver Test crashing in Release Build [ Works fine in Debug ]

Tags: c++, windows, mongodb, release, mongo-cxx-driver

I have build the mongodb cxx binaries in windows following the steps described [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/).

I have created the Test application as mentioned in the steps.
On **release builds**, the application throws `bad allocation` exception:
`std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0047EB60`] in this line :

```
mongocxx::uri muri{ uri_string };
```

The same code works with Debug build.

Could someone please help me to fix the issue in Release build ?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of when the error occurs using Visual Studio's debugger?

Comment: My issue got resolved after I built mongocxx and bsoncxx in Release and used that
Thanks for the support

Comment: Stack trace:
  vcruntime140d.dll!59aa4970() Unknown
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for vcruntime140d.dll] 
  [External Code] 
> bsoncxx.dll!boost::basic_string_ref<char,std::char_traits<char> >::to_string() Line 113 C++
  bsoncxx.dll!bsoncxx::v_noabi::string::view_or_value::terminated() Line 27 C++
  mongocxx.dll!573b5124() Unknown

Comment: Awesome! Just to make sure, this stacktrace is from before you fixed the issue, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue got resolved after I built mongocxx and bsoncxx in Release and used that. Previously I built those in Debug and Test Application in release.
Need to match the target configuration.

Comment: Build LIBSON in 64 : cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver"

Comment: C Driver in 64: cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"   "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver"   "-DBSON_ROOT_DIR=C:\mongo-c-driver"

Comment: Cxx Driver : 
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:\mongo-c-driver     -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost_1_64_0 -DLIBBSON_DIR=c:\mongo-c-driver -DLIBMONGOC_DIR=c:\mongo-c-driver


Win64 : optional and should be same as c driver